# NodeJS undefined is not an object (evaluating 'input.files[0])

Tags: node.js, input, next.js

I have the following error happening when I try and run my nextjs app.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'input.files[0]')
```

The reason must be the following

```
 validateAudioUpload(input){
      var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var file = input.files[0];
    
      if (file) {
          var image = new Image();
    
          image.onload = function() {
              if (this.width) {
                   console.log('Image has width, I think it is real image');
                   //TODO: upload to backend
              }
          };
    
          image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      }
    }
```

in the render return section I have

```
 <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
                    <Form.Label>Please select an Image File (500w x 500h)</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="file" onChange={this.validateAudioUpload(this)}/>
                  </Form.Group>
```

Now because when the page loads it must be trying to run the onChange and it is getting NULL as there is no file selected by the user.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple check before accessing the value:

```
if (!input?.files || input.files.length === 0) return

var file = input.files[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 validateAudioUpload = (input) => {
      var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var file = input.files[0];
    
      if (file) {
          var image = new Image();
    
          image.onload = function() {
              if (this.width) {
                   console.log('Image has width, I think it is real image');
                   //TODO: upload to backend
              }
          };
    
          image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      }
    }
```

```
<Form.Control type="file" onChange={this.validateAudioUpload}/>
```

Comment: It works, kinda - but it's not picking up the selected image it's returning unidentified    var file = input.files[0];
      alert(file);